# Need to make my Batch Program more compact

Tags: batch-file, dictionary

ive tried to make a dictionary program...

```
echo off
Title Afrikaans-English Dictionary
color 0A
cls
echo Created by TheAsainBuffalo
echo Created on 2015-07-25
echo Last Updated 2015-07-25
echo =============================
:Again
set /p Answer=Type in Afikaans Word: 
if %Answer%==afsluit echo English Meaning: to finish
if %Answer%==afrighter echo English Meaning: coach
if %Answer%==agterbland echo English Meaning: blankcover
if %Answer%==aktueel echo English Meaning: actual
if %Answer%==atletiekbaan echo English Meaning: athletics track
if %Answer%==bannoppervlak echo English Meaning: track
if %Answer%==bespeigel echo English Meaning: contemplate
if %Answer%==bespreek echo English Meaning: discuss
if %Answer%==bladsynommer echo English Meaning: page number
if %Answer%==boodskiet echo English Meaning: archery
if %Answer%==draf echo English Meaning: jog
if %Answer%==fiksie echo English Meaning: fiction
if %Answer%==flapteks echo English Meaning: blurb
if %Answer%==hawermout echo English Meaning: oats
if %Answer%==heuweloefeninge echo English Meaning: hill exercises
if %Answer%==hoofkarakter echo English Meaning: protagonist
if %Answer%==illustrasie echo English Meaning: illustration
if %Answer%==inheems echo English Meaning: indigenous
if %Answer%==inhoudsopgowe echo English Meaning: index
if %Answer%==inligting echo English Meaning: information
if %Answer%==inligtingsboeke echo English Meaning: 
if %Answer%==juig echo English Meaning: cheer/applaud
if %Answer%==krale echo English Meaning: beads
if %Answer%==maatskappy echo English Meaning: company
if %Answer%==muurbal echo English Meaning: squash
if %Answer%==nie-fiksie echo English Meaning: non-fiction
if %Answer%==oefeninge echo English Meaning: practice/training
if %Answer%==oplossings echo English Meaning: solutions
if %Answer%==opwarmingsoefeinge echo English Meaning: warm ups
if %Answer%==outeur echo echo English Meaning: author
if %Answer%==pedry echo English Meaning: equestrain
if %Answer%==reken echo English Meaning: desktop
if %Answer%==rekenaar echo English Meaning: PC/Computer
if %Answer%==riller echo English Meaning: thriller (book)
if %Answer%==roei echo English Meaning: paddling
if %Answer%==selfversekerd echo English Meaning: confident
if %Answer%==speurder echo English Meaning: detective
if %Answer%==spieël echo English Meaning: mirror
if %Answer%==spieel echo Possible English Meaning: mirror
if %Answer%==sterspronge echo English Meaning: star jumps
if %Answer%==steun echo English Meaning: support
if %Answer%==stopharlosie echo English Meaning: stopwatch
if %Answer%==tafeldoek echo English Meaning: tablecloth
if %Answer%==teneergedruk echo English Meaning: depressed
if %Answer%==titel echo English Meaning: title
if %Answer%==tjiekilit echo English Meaning: chicklit (book)
if %Answer%==trampopies echo English Meaning: drummies
if %Answer%==tydskrif echo English Meaning: magazine
if %Answer%==verbysteek echo English Meaning: pass
if %Answer%==visie echo English Meaning: pass
if %Answer%==vlugbal echo English Meaning: volleyball
if %Answer%==voorbland echo English Meaning: front cover
if %Answer%==waarheid echo English Meaning: truth
if %Answer%==weerkaatsing echo English Meaning: reflection
if %Answer%==wegspringblokke echo English Meaning: starting blocks
goto Again
::Finished until 18 Feb 2015 (boodskiet)
```

however i wanted to make it easier by just having something like

```
set waarheid=truth
set weerkaatsing=reflection
set (Afrikaans Word)=(English Word)
set /p Answer=Type in Afrikaans Word: 
echo Definition %Answer%
```

Sorry if I'm such a newbie or whatever... My problem is that I need the User Input to prompt the English Word/Meaning of the Afrikaans Word if that makes any sense... Thanks if anyone tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an external text file as "database":

```
afsluit=to finish
afrighter=coach
agterbland=blankcover
aktueel=actual
atletiekbaan=athletics track
etc. etc. etc.
```

shortening your batch file to "code only":

```
:Again
set "Answer="
set /p "Answer=Type in Afikaans Word: "
if "%Answer%"=="" goto :Again
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in ('findstr /i /b /c:"%Answer%" dictionary.txt') do (
  echo the english term for %%i is %%j.
)
if /i "%Answer%" neq "exit" goto :Again
echo bye.
```

of course, this is only the basics. There should also be some more error testing ("word not in database")

Answer (score 0):

This type of applications are written in a much simpler way with the aid of an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990). In the solution below, the translation array is stored in the same Batch file, so no additional data file is needed.

Also, this program have an interesting trick: it helps you to easily define new translation terms!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Title Afrikaans-English Dictionary
color 0A
cls
echo Created by TheAsainBuffalo
echo Created on 2015-07-25
echo Last Updated 2015-07-25
echo =============================

call :CreateTranslationArray

:Again
echo/
set "Afrikaans="
set /p "Afrikaans=Type in Afrikaans Word: "
if not defined Afrikaans goto :EOF
if defined English[%Afrikaans%] (
   echo English Meaning: !English[%Afrikaans%]!
) else (
   echo I don't know the English translation of Afrikaans "%Afrikaans%" yet
   set /P "English=Please give me such translation: "
   set "English[%Afrikaans%]=!English!"
   echo set "English[%Afrikaans%]=!English!">> "%~F0"
)
goto Again
::Finished until 18 Feb 2015 (boodskiet)

:CreateTranslationArray
set "English[afsluit]=to finish"
set "English[afrighter]=coach"
set "English[agterbland]=blankcover"
set "English[aktueel]=actual"
set "English[atletiekbaan]=athletics track"
```

Comment: do you know, if there is a limit for environment variables (memory)? (I'm not sure, that's why I put the data in an extra file (could also be the end of the batch file , if a "single file solution" is preferred)

Comment: @Stephan: The maximum environment size is 64 MB. See the Note below "Setting environment variables" at [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Should be enough... Thank you for this info, I couldn't find it ad hoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the dictionary after your code within your script, and use FINDSTR to locate the correct word pair, and FOR /F to parse the result.

Below is a nifty version that supports both Afrikaans to English, and English to Afrikaans. Yet it only requires one dictionary, and the exact same code for both!. I make heavy use of double expansion, as in `!%var%!`.

```
echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
Title Afrikaans-English Dictionary
color 0A
set "input=Afrikaans"
set "output=English"
set "beginEnglishSearch=^:::.*:"
set "beginAfrikaansSearch=^:::"
set "endEnglishSearch=$"
set "endAfrikaansSearch=:"
cls

:Prompt
set "word="
set /p "word=Type in %input% Word (or + to switch):"
if not defined word (
  color
  title Command Prompt
  exit /b
)
if "!word!"=="+" (
  set "input=%output%"
  set "output=%input%"
  cls
  goto :Prompt
)
::Result
cls
(
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in (
    'findstr /ric:"!begin%input%Search!!word!!end%input%Search!" "%~f0"'
  ) do (
    set "Afrikaans=%%A"
    set "English=%%B"
  )
) && (
  echo %input%: !%input%!
  echo %output%: !%output%!
) || (
  echo !word! not found.
)
echo(
echo(
goto :Prompt

::---------- Afrikaans-English Dictionary below ---------------
:::afsluit:to finish
:::afrighter:coach
:::agterbland:blankcover
:::aktueel:actual
:::atletiekbaan:athletics track
:::bannoppervlak:track
:::bespeigel:contemplate
:::bespreek:discuss
:::bladsynommer:page number
:::boodskiet:archery
:::draf:jog
:::fiksie:fiction
:::flapteks:blurb
:::hawermout:oats
:::heuweloefeninge:hill exercises
:::hoofkarakter:protagonist
:::illustrasie:illustration
:::inheems:indigenous
:::inhoudsopgowe:index
:::inligting:information
:::inligtingsboeke:
:::juig:cheer
:::krale:beads
:::maatskappy:company
:::muurbal:squash
:::nie-fiksie:non-fiction
:::oefeninge:training
:::oplossings:solutions
:::opwarmingsoefeinge:warm ups
:::outeur:author
:::pedry:equestrain
:::reken:desktop
:::rekenaar:computer
:::riller:thriller
:::roei:paddling
:::selfversekerd:confident
:::speurder:detective
:::spieël:mirror
:::spieel:mirror
:::sterspronge:star jumps
:::steun:support
:::stopharlosie:stopwatch
:::tafeldoek:tablecloth
:::teneergedruk:depressed
:::titel:title
:::tjiekilit:chicklit
:::trampopies:drummies
:::tydskrif:magazine
:::verbysteek:pass
:::visie:pass
:::vlugbal:volleyball
:::voorbland:front cover
:::waarheid:truth
:::weerkaatsing:reflection
:::wegspringblokke:starting blocks
```